# How to run specific test cases or spec in intelliJ Idea IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, geb

We are using geb framework for our testing with IntelliJ IDE. many times we need to run only few test cases in a a spec. For that either we are running the whole spec or one by one. Is there any way to run the specified test cases?

Comment: I am not familiar with the geb framework, but if you are running the tests via maven then you can use maven profiles and annotations to run subsets of the tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Spock then you can mark all the test cases you want to run with @IgnoreRest and then run the whole spec in IntelliJ - only the marked test cases will be run.

If you want to build suites of tests you can use either `@IgnoreIf`/`@Require` annotations or Spock config file. Both these techniques are described in [a blog post](http://blog.proxerd.pl/article/segregating-spock-specifications-with-spockconfig-groovy-and-annotations) I wrote some time ago.

Comment: thats a good way to run few test cases but we have around 600 test cases and if I want to run 300 test cases, it will be a time consuming effort. Also what If want to run specific test cases between differetn specs. Is there a way?